# SOAP methods with point on its name description

Tags: python, soap, nusoap, suds, soappy

Ok, i've a problem consuming a soap client with python with a soap server that gives method's name with points on it like 'MyClass.mymethod(xs:string)'.

This is cause by a PHP lib called nusoap that can handle those types of name with it.

I've tried with suds and SOAPy without success.

Anyone have solve a similar issue?

Thanks.

Comment: could you show us a bit of the client code you tried and also the wsdl if it is available..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To negate the use of a period in the method name you could access is using the map of function avaiable on the client object.
E.G.

```
return = client.service[0]['MyClass.mymethod']('input string')
```

That's a best guess with teh available information

Hope that helps